# Is there a way to link project task to document submission and approval

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-integration, project-online

We have few content writer that are paid by the hour. And they submit their documents on sharepoint. They usually bill 10X more than their actual time(We were even billed 30 hrs for a document copied from online).

I was told there is no way of tracking time spent on document directly without purchasing additional software. So is it possible to create a task on Project online and set maximum work for a task and once the document is submitted can the task be automatically marked as completed and user can submit Actual work in the timesheet.

SO my question would be is there a way to link project online task to sharepoint online document submission. We are trying to come up with a new process for a non profit. So any better solution will be helpful.